# Correct gunicorn.conf to get environmental variables for Django use

Tags: django, virtualenv, gunicorn

I am deploying a Django app on my VPS using `Nginx` as the web server and `Gunicorn` installed in `virtualenv`. (I am using `virtualenv` with `virtualenvwrapper`.)

When I run `Gunicorn` like this, environment variables (such as database password, name) can be found:

```
workon virtual_env_name
# from my_project's root path
gunicorn my_project.wsgi --bind localhost:9000 --daemon
# this works
```

I exported the environment variables this way:

```
# /home/user_name/Envs/virtual_env_name/bin/postactivate
export DATABASE_PASSWORD="secret_password"
```

However the way below does not (whether or not `virtual_env_name` is activated):

```
sudo service gunicorn start
# env variables can't be found - KeyError thrown
```

This is how my `gunicorn.conf` script looks like:

```
start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectadly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid user_name
setgid www-data
chdir /home/user_name/my_project

exec /home/user_name/Envs/virtual_env_name/bin/gunicorn \
    --name=my_project \
    --pythonpath=/home/user_name/my_project \
    --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 \
    my_project.wsgi:application
```

I can confirm this `gunicorn.conf` works if I hard code all the password, keys into my Django's `settings.py` instead of using `os.environ[..]`.

What do I need to do to make my environment variables found when I start `Gunicorn` with `sudo service start`? What's the difference between the first and second way? Thanks.

Comment: Please kindly correct me (or edit my question) if I use any terms wrong or ambiguously.

Comment: Please show output of `pip freeze` on Your system and on virtualenv.

Comment: Here is my [pip freeze for system](https://gist.github.com/jnshey/3b37eb8bfc2f1392d355) and [pip freeze for virtualenv](https://gist.github.com/jnshey/24acc400606bb91d3de7).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to define those variables inside gunicorn.conf.

```
env DATABASE_PASSWORD="secret_password"
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it works. But why can't the env variables in postactivate be seen when I use `sudo service gunicorn start`?

Comment: One more question, why doesn't `env DEBUG=False` in `gunicorn.conf` disable debug mode for Django? In `settings.py`, I use `DEBUG = os.environ['DEBUG']`.

Comment: First, because upstart starts your job in a completely new environment. And secondly, because the variables are all strings, and "False" is boolean true.

Comment: Thanks. I now use `eval(os.environ['DEBUG'])`. Are there better methods such as making use of Truthy and Falsey values?

Comment: It's a bad solution. When You remove Django from global packages (look at Your pip freeze results) then Your application does not start properly.

Comment: @Thomasz Jakub Rup I think when I use virtual env's gunicorn by `/home/user_name/Envs/virtual_env_name/bin/gunicorn`, I am also using virtual env's django?

Answer (score 1):

You don't run the code in virtualenv.

Instead of `exec` use

```
pre-start script
    workon virtual_env_name
end script

script
    gunicorn \
        --name=my_project \
        --pythonpath=/home/user_name/my_project \
        --bind=127.0.0.1:9000 \
        my_project.wsgi:application
end script
```

`workon` update Your `$PATH` env variable.